# Space between previous html element and flexbox. Why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm facing the challenge that adding `display: flex` to a div creates extra space between the previous html element and the div. Why is this?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simen236/uL407x3v/15/) illustrating the issue.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<div></div>
<hr>
<div class="flex-container"></div>
<hr>
```

Why the extra space created between the second hr and the flex-container?
Inspection in Chrome yields 0 height for the flex-container.

Thanks!

Comment: Flex container margins *don't collapse*. See the duplicate for details.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins